# Parallel Computing with Julia @parallel and SharedArray

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I have been trying to implement some parallel programming in Julia using `@parallel` and `SharedArray`s.

```
Xi = Array{Float64}([0.0, 450.0, 450.0, 0.0, 0.0, 450.0, 450.0, 0.0])
Yi = Array{Float64}([0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 600.0, 0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 600.0])
Zi = Array{Float64}([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 400.0, 400.0, 400.0, 400.0])
Xj = Array{Float64}([0.0, 450.0, 450.0, 0.0, 0.0, 450.0, 450.0, 0.0])
Yj = Array{Float64}([0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 600.0, 0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 600.0])
Zj = Array{Float64}([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 400.0, 400.0, 400.0, 400.0])
L = Array{Float64}([400.0, 400.0, 400.0, 400.0, 450.0, 600.0, 450.0, 600.0])
Rot = Array{Float64}([90.0, 90.0, 90.0, 90.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
```

Obviously these vectors will be huge, but for simplicity I just put this limited size.

This is the operation without parallel computing:

```
function jt_transcoord(Xi, Yi, Zi, Xj, Yj, Zj, Rot, L)
r = Vector(length(Xi))
for i in 1:length(Xi)
    rxX = (Xj[i] - Xi[i]) / L[i]
    rxY = (Yj[i] - Yi[i]) / L[i]
    rxZ = (Zj[i] - Zi[i]) / L[i]
        if rxX == 0 && rxY == 0
            r[i] = [0 0 rxZ; cosd(Rot[i]) -rxZ*sind(Rot[i]) 0; sind(Rot[i]) rxZ*cosd(Rot[i]) 0]
        else
            R=sqrt(rxX^2+rxY^2)
            r21=(-rxX*rxZ*cosd(Rot[i])+rxY*sind(Rot[i]))/R
            r22=(-rxY*rxZ*cosd(Rot[i])-rxX*sind(Rot[i]))/R
            r23=R*cosd(Rot[i])
            r31=(rxX*rxZ*sind(Rot[i])+rxY*cosd(Rot[i]))/R
            r32=(rxY*rxZ*sind(Rot[i])-rxX*cosd(Rot[i]))/R
            r33=-R*sind(Rot[i])
            r[i] = [rxX rxY rxZ;r21 r22 r23;r31 r32 r33]
        end
end
return r
end
```

The returned value is basically an array that contains a matrix in each vector row. That looks something like this:

```
r = 
[[0.0 0.0 1.0; 0.0 -1.0 0.0; 1.0 0.0 0.0], 
[0.0 0.0 1.0; 0.0 -1.0 0.0; 1.0 0.0 0.0], 
[0.0 0.0 1.0; 0.0 -1.0 0.0; 1.0 0.0 0.0], 
[0.0 0.0 1.0; 0.0 -1.0 0.0; 1.0 0.0 0.0], 
[1.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 -0.0 1.0; 0.0 -1.0 -0.0], 
[0.0 1.0 0.0; 0.0 -0.0 1.0; 1.0 0.0 -0.0], 
[-1.0 0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0 1.0; 0.0 1.0 -0.0], 
[0.0 -1.0 0.0; -0.0 0.0 1.0; -1.0 -0.0 -0.0]]
```

This is my function using `@parallel`. First of all I need to convert the vectors to `SharedArray`s:

```
Xi = convert(SharedArray, Xi)
Yi = convert(SharedArray, Yi)
Zi = convert(SharedArray, Zi)
Xj = convert(SharedArray, Xj)
Yj = convert(SharedArray, Yj)
Zj = convert(SharedArray, Zj)
L = convert(SharedArray, L)
Rot = convert(SharedArray, Rot)
```

This the same code but using `@parallel`

```
function jt_transcoord_parallel(Xi, Yi, Zi, Xj, Yj, Zj, Rot, L)
r = SharedArray{Float64}(zeros((length(Xi),1)))
@parallel for i in 1:length(Xi)
    rxX = (Xj[i] - Xi[i]) / L[i]
    rxY = (Yj[i] - Yi[i]) / L[i]
    rxZ = (Zj[i] - Zi[i]) / L[i]
        if rxX == 0 && rxY == 0
            r[i] = [0 0 rxZ; cosd(Rot[i]) -rxZ*sind(Rot[i]) 0; sind(Rot[i]) rxZ*cosd(Rot[i]) 0]
        else
            R=sqrt(rxX^2+rxY^2)
            r21=(-rxX*rxZ*cosd(Rot[i])+rxY*sind(Rot[i]))/R
            r22=(-rxY*rxZ*cosd(Rot[i])-rxX*sind(Rot[i]))/R
            r23=R*cosd(Rot[i])
            r31=(rxX*rxZ*sind(Rot[i])+rxY*cosd(Rot[i]))/R
            r32=(rxY*rxZ*sind(Rot[i])-rxX*cosd(Rot[i]))/R
            r33=-R*sind(Rot[i])
            r[i] = [rxX rxY rxZ;r21 r22 r23;r31 r32 r33]
        end
end
return r
end
```

I just got a vector of zeros. My question is: Is there a way to implement this function using `@parallel` in Julia and get the same results that I got in my original function?

Comment: is `r` visible to all of the processes that act on it? it looks like you convert `Arrays`s to `SharedArray`s, which can change the way that the `SharedArray` is distributed over its constituent processes. what is the output of `procs(r)` and `localindexes(r)`?

Comment: also it would help if you clarified precisely what question you want answered.

Comment: @KevinLKeys since the vectors are so small I am working only with 1 process. `procs(r)` is giving `1` and `localindexes(r)` is giving `1:8`. I also edit the my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions `jt_transcoord` and `jt_transcoord_parallel` have major coding flaws.

In `jt_transcoord`, you are assigning an array to a vector element position. For example, you write `r = Vector(length(Xi))` and then assign `r[i] = [rxX rxY rxZ;r21 r22 r23;r31 r32 r33]`. But `r[i]` should be a *number*, and you instead assign it a 3x3 *matrix*. I suspect that Julia is quietly changing types for you.

`SharedArray` objects will not admit this lax type conversion behavior. The components of a `SharedArray` must be of a single [primitive type](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/types/#Primitive-Types-1) such as `Float64`, and `Vector{Matrix}` is not a primitive type. Open a Julia v0.6 REPL and copy/paste the following code:

```
r = SharedArray{Float64}(length(Xi))

for i in 1:length(Xi)
    rxX = (Xj[i] - Xi[i]) / L[i]
    rxY = (Yj[i] - Yi[i]) / L[i]
    rxZ = (Zj[i] - Zi[i]) / L[i]
        if rxX == 0 && rxY == 0
            r[i] = [0 0 rxZ; cosd(Rot[i]) -rxZ*sind(Rot[i]) 0; sind(Rot[i]) rxZ*cosd(Rot[i]) 0]
        else
            R    = sqrt(rxX^2+rxY^2)
            r21  = (-rxX*rxZ*cosd(Rot[i])+rxY*sind(Rot[i]))/R
            r22  = (-rxY*rxZ*cosd(Rot[i])-rxX*sind(Rot[i]))/R
            r23  = R*cosd(Rot[i])
            r31  = (rxX*rxZ*sind(Rot[i])+rxY*cosd(Rot[i]))/R
            r32  = (rxY*rxZ*sind(Rot[i])-rxX*cosd(Rot[i]))/R
            r33  = -R*sind(Rot[i])
            r[i] = [rxX rxY rxZ;r21 r22 r23;r31 r32 r33]
        end
end
```

On my end, I get:

```
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Array{Float64,2} to an object of type Float64
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Float64(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
Stacktrace:
 [1] setindex!(::SharedArray{Float64,2}, ::Array{Float64,2}, ::Int64) at ./sharedarray.jl:483
 [2] macro expansion at ./REPL[26]:6 [inlined]
 [3] anonymous at ./<missing>:?
```

Essentially, Julia is telling you that it cannot assign a matrix to a `SharedArray` vector.

What are your options?

- If you insist on having a `Vector{Matrix}` return type, then use `r = Vector{Matrix{Float64}}(length(Xi))` in `jt_transcoord`. But you cannot use `SharedArray`s for this since `Vector{Matrix}` is not an admissible primitive type.
- Alternatively, if you are willing to operate with tensors (i.e. 3-way arrays) then you can use pseudocode A below. But `SharedArray` computing will only help you if you carefully account for which process owns which portion of the tensor. Otherwise, the processes will need to communicate with each other, and your parallelized function could execute very slowly.
- If you are willing to lay your 3x3 matrices in a 3n x 3 columnwise fashion, then you can use pseudocode B below.

**Pseudocode A**

```
function jt_transcoord_tensor(Xi, Yi, Zi, Xj, Yj, Zj, Rot, L)
    # initialize array
    r = Array{Float64}(3,3,length(Xi))
    # r = SharedArray{Float64,3}((3,3,length(Xi))) # for SharedArrays

    for i in 1:length(Xi)
    # @parallel for i in 1:length(Xi) # for SharedArrays
        # other code...
        r[:,:,i] = [0 0 rxZ; cosd(Rot[i]) -rxZ*sind(Rot[i]) 0; sind(Rot[i]) rxZ*cosd(Rot[i]) 0]
        # other code...
        r[:,:,i] = [rxX rxY rxZ;r21 r22 r23;r31 r32 r33]
        end
    end
    return r
end
```

**Pseudocode B**

```
function jt_transcoord_parallel(Xi, Yi, Zi, Xj, Yj, Zj, Rot, L)
    n = length(Xi)
    r = SharedArray{Float64}((3*n,3))
    @parallel for i in 1:length(Xi)
            # other code...
            r[(3*(i-1)+1):3*(i),:] = [0 0 rxZ; cosd(Rot[i]) -rxZ*sind(Rot[i]) 0; sind(Rot[i]) rxZ*cosd(Rot[i]) 0]
            # other code...
            r[(3*(i-1)+1):3*(i),:] = [rxX rxY rxZ;r21 r22 r23;r31 r32 r33]
        end
    end
    return r
end
```

Comment: In Pseudocode B in line 3 `r = SharedArray{Float64}(Float64,(3*n,3))` The second `Float64,` is causing an error. After correcting that detail both Pseudocode options solve the issue I was having.

Comment: I corrected that line in light of @RolandoAdriánVillena's comment.